# Find all triples $(p; q; r)$ of primes such that $pq = r+ 1$ and $2(p ^ 2+q ^ 2) =r ^ 2 + 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have to find all triples $(p; q; r)$ of primes such that $pq = r+ 1$ and $2(p ^ 2+q ^ 2) =r ^ 2 + 1$. This question was asked in the 2013 mumbai region RMO but i could not find a solution to it. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: This is not an answer. Hence, posting in comments. Squaring the first equation and subtracting the second from it, we get $p^2q^2 - 2 ( p^2 + q^2 ) = 2r$ suggesting that atleast one of $p$ or $q$ should be even. This in turn implies $r$ is odd as $r + 1 = pq$, an even number. If $r$ is odd, then $r^2 + 1$ is a number of the form $4k + 2$ which can't be the case unless exactly one of $p$ or $q$ is odd.

Comment: Two cases: $r = 2$ or not. The $r = 2$ case has no solutions, so $r$ is not $2$. So $r+1$ is even. So $p$ or $q$ is $2$. Let's say $p$ is. Then $8 + 2q^2 - r^2 + 1$...

Comment: So as @John suggests, let's take $p = 2$ without loss of generality. Then, we have two equations
\begin{align*}
  2q &= r + 1\\
  2q^2 + 8 &= r^2 + 1.
\end{align*}
We then get $r^2 - 2r - 15 = 0$. I think I will stop at this point ;-)

Comment: @CameronBuie I didn't see the restriction to primes. To explore possible general solutions note that $2(p^2+q^2)+4pq=r^2+1+4r+4$ gives $2(p+q)^2=(r+2)^2+1$

Comment: @CameronBuie I hadn't noticed the typo - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mark: No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $r^2+1=2(p^2+q^2)$ is even, so $r^2$ is odd, and so $r$ is odd. But then $pq=r-1$ is even. Thus, $p$ and/or $q$ must be an even prime.

What happens next depends on whether you are considering negative numbers as potential primes. I will proceed as though you are. Let's assume that $p$ is an even prime, so that $p^2=4.$ Squaring the first equation then shows us that $$4q^2=r^2+2r+1,$$ while multiplying the second equation by $2$ gives us $$16+4q^2=2r^2+2,$$ meaning $$4q^2=2r^2-14.$$ Thus, $$2r^2-14=r^2+2r+1\\r^2-2r-15=0\\(r-5)(r+3)=0$$ and so either $r=5$ or $r=-3.$ But we cannot have $r=-3,$, though, since then we would have $$4q^2=r^2+2r-1=9-6+1=4,$$ so $q^2=1,$ which is impossible, since $q$ is prime. Thus, we must have $r=5.$ So, our original equations become $$pq=6$$ and $$8+2q^2=26.$$ Hence, we find the triples $(2,3,5)$ and $(-2,-3,5).$

Assuming that $q$ is an even prime likewise gets us the triples $(3,2,5)$ and $(-3,-2,5).$

From the work above, we can also see that there are only two viable triples if we are *not* considering negative numbers as potential primes.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ r = pq-1\, $ must be odd, so, wlog, $\,q=2$. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

First, we square the first equation. We have: $p^2q^2=r^2+2r+1$.
 If we plug $r^2+1$ we would have: $p^2q^2=2(p^2+q^2+r)$. Since $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers and the RHS is even, at least one of them should be $2$.
 Without loss of generality we take $p=2$. We have: $4q^2=2(4+q^2+r)$ so $q^2=r+4$. If we plug this into the second equation, we have: $2(4+r+4)=r^2+1$ so $r^2-2r+15=0$.
 The solutions are $r=-3,5$ but $-3$ is not a prime number so $r=5$. Plugging this into the first equation, we get $2q=6$ so $q=3$. 
Thus, the only triplets would be: $(p,q,r)=(2,3,5),(3,2,5)$
P.S.: As Singhal suggested, Technically −3 is a prime. But in here it does not lead to any solutions

Comment: Technically $-3$ is a prime but in this case, it does not lead to any solutions.

Comment: @Singhal Well, according to Wikipedia, A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. So i don't think it would be a prime number!

Comment: I consider the more general definition of an element being prime in a ring whenever it makes sense (for example, in case of $\Bbb{Z}$) ;-)

Comment: @Singhal Oh, in that case, you are right :) Thanks! I will add it to my answer :)

Comment: Also, and more interestingly in this case, $-2$ is a(nother even) prime in $\Bbb Z.$

Comment: Here is a better way, IMO, although very much equivalent, to go after assuming $p=2$:
$$2q=r+1$$
$$4q^2=r^2+1+2r$$
$$4q^2=2\cdot 4+ 2q^2+2r$$
$$q^2-4=r$$
$$(q-2)(q+2)=r$$
Since $r$ is prime, $q-2=1$, hence $q=2$ and $r=5$. And because $p$ and $q$ are symmetric, the only triples are ...

Comment: @Sawarnik Oh thanks...! That was a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Solution.If p and q are both odd, then r = pq - 1 is even so r= 2. But in this case pq>=3*3 = 9 and hence there are no solutions. This proves that either p= 2 or q= 2. If p= 2 then we have 2q = r + 1 and 8 + 2q^2 = r^2+ 1. Multiplying the second equation by 2 we get 2r^2+ 2 = 16 + (2q)^2 = 16 + (r+ 1)^2. Rearranging the terms, we have r^2-2r-15 = 0,or equivalently (r+ 3)(r-5) = 0. This proves that r= 5 and hence q= 3. Similarly,if q= 2 then r= 5 and p= 3. Thus the only two solutions are (p;q;r) = (2;3;5) and(p;q;r) = (3;2;5).